# Is it a felony to drive a car that was recalled and poses a danger?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, safety

Is it a felony to drive a car that was recalled and poses a danger? Let's say a car was recalled due to faulty brakes. Is it a felony to still drive that car without having it repaired by the manufacturer? What happens if you weren't aware? I heard that saying you weren't aware of a law is not an excuse, but I am wondering if it also applies to car recalls. Assume that's it's in the U.S.

Comment: In what jurisdiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlikely, but specific facts may change this.

The fact a vehicle gets the approval of the NHTSA and/or other safety regulatory bodies will probably mean that it already passed a certain level of safety testing, and any reasons for a recall will only surface after orders of magnitude greater sample and/or testing time. Therefore, the probability of causing endangering participants in traffic and others are negligible.

The duty of notice will most likely be on the manufacturer under a product liability theory.

Driving continuously and/or repeatedly after notice may be a different matter if it actually results in harming one — theoretically even oneself.

Comment: There's a recall on one of my cars for a rear suspension that I can't get fixed because the dealer in my area doesn't have the parts to do it. It might cause an accident according to the recall notice. I guess I should be documenting our calls to the dealership.

Comment: In California? Still under warranty?

Comment: No it’s an older car and we live in a small city in VA. There’s pandemic related supply chain issues I think.

Comment: @ColleenV so sorry for somehow missing to reply to this: Yeah, I'm not familiar with VA consumer or vehicle law unfortunately — other than the Moss-Magnusson that effects the states.

Comment: No worries. We solved the problem by trading it in at a large dealership for a new car that wasn’t a discontinued model ;)

Comment: Great, glad to hear it resolved then!